# Does load resistor value in constant current setup affect power delivered from source/battery?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, batteries, discharge

I am bulding a battery pack of 48v using 18650 cells salvaged from laptop batteries. I have to test them for their capacity to use in my project of converting bycycle to electric. So i have couple of imax B6 charger/discharger and a HTC 240Duo charger/discharger. which can do only 1 or 2 cells discharge at a time. so for large quantity of testing i designed a circuit using Arduino mega 2560 mini version and LM324 as comparator. I have attached circuit diagram along with this and also the pcb i t.hat is designed. i have used the code from brettwatty's
[arduino-mega-8x-charger-discharger-offline](https://github.com/brettwatty/arduino-mega-8x-charger-discharger-offline)
[Circuit diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTz9f.jpg)
[PCB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVWIo.jpg)

In this i am calculating the mAh with constant current for e.g., 500mA or 0.5A and if the discharge process continues for 4 hrs. then, the capacity would be
(0.5)*(4*3600)*(1/3600) = 2000mAH.
Here i am not considering the load. If we discharge the battery with different Load resistance and keeping the same current value as 0.5A does the calculation to find capacity has aslo to be changed?

[image: Circuit diagram]
I am reading voltages in two points A and B  as battery and load voltages respectively(shown in circuit diagram fig 1&2). And using load resistance value, calculating the current drawn. If the current drawn deviates, then will adjust the PWM signal such that the current remains same even if the battery voltage decreases.

If the same is calculated using resistance with four hours of discharge, then

```
fig-1, value R = 2ohms,I =0.5A, power I2R = 0.25*2 = 0.5W, for 4H = 2WH -> 2/3.7 = 540mAh
fig-2, value R = 5ohms,I =0.5A, power I2R = 0.25*5 = 1.25W,for 4H = 5WH -> 5/3.7 = 1351mAH
calculated without resistance value included (0.5)*(4*3600)*(1/3600) = 2000mAH.
```

[image: PCB]

Sometimes when you keep on thinking too much and miss something completely silly thing. So i am asking all of you anyone who is able to tell me the mistakes i am doing and also to demistify the capacity calculation.

Currently I have just finished coding and now i am tesing the accuracy of the system i have built. And came up with this doubt. Which method to use for calculating the capacity of battery, for my setup above. Or any method which i can improve calculating the capacity.

If this is not the place for this kind of question then please let me know which will be the suitable platform for this type of question.

Thank you.

Comment: If you search my answers on battery capacitance and ESR, and Peukert’s Law you will see some decline of capacity as the std rate is normalized for 1C=20h, while fresh cells may see minor variation compared to aged ones with higher ESR.  It is most important to match cells as the weakest cell is the weakest link in a chain and ages the fastest. ... from Overcharge or undercharge voltage. Otherwise generally looks good.  There is also at least 2 time constants due to RC1, RC2 effects which show as short and long term memory (capacitance in kiloFarads)

Comment: Are you sure PWM is similar enough to true current control? I.e., is one amp with 50% duty similar enough to 0.5 amps? You are currently probably using PWM to compensate for a voltage change from 4.2 to 3.0 V, so I gather the full battery will be running at 40% higher current (twice the power). Intuitively, this will not give an accurate value if your real world discharge will be 0.5 A. It will give you an accurate model to understand varying loads between 0.5-0.7A depending on battery charge. (My verbal hedging is because I don't know the mechanics of battery degradation.)

Comment: @piojo PWM is the only way i found useful and easily change the discharge amps from 0.5A to 1.5A or max possible Amps simply by changing the duty cycle. Which is not possible if i use resistors. Currently the duty cycle is around 30%-60% changes according the load resistance. I am changing the PWM duty cycle to maintain the drop across the load. For e.g., 1v drop across 2ohm load for 0.5A current. so as the battery voltage decreases, the drop across load changes and thus current so this is when i change pwm. I think this is what you also implied.

Comment: I want to know the capacity in test condition or similar condition for all the batteries. So that i can make calculated guess that this pack has this much power in theory and can discharge minimum x amps max y amps. In real world scenario, it depends on the pack, as how many of these cells are in parallel. so 40% higher or 20%lower depends on the pack.

Comment: @vrOom You could use a a darlington transistor, adjusted by your feedback using your op amps. It would need to dissipate up to around 2 watts if my math is right, so that long heat sink might not be enough.